# LongListSelector.SelectedItem can't cast to my object class

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, longlistselector

I have a LongListSelector that is populated with List which contains objects from SQLite database:

```
 protected override async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
  SQLiteAsyncConnection conn = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(DB_PATH);
  var query = conn.Table<Prasanja>().Where(x => x.id == 3);
  var result = await query.ToListAsync();
  foreach (var item in result)
  {
       var query1 = conn.Table<Odgovori>()
       .Where(y => y.Prasanja_id == item.id);

        txtPrasanje.Text = item.Tekst;
        var resultOdgovori = await query1.ToListAsync();

         foreach (var itemOdgovor in resultOdgovori)
        {
            Lista.Add(itemOdgovor.Odgovor.ToString());
            lstOdgovori.ItemsSource = Lista;
        }
   }
```

What I want is when one of the LongListSelector items is tapped that I get the specific object tapped, and have the ability to use that object properties.Here is my code:

```
   private void lstOdgovori_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
   LongListSelector selector = sender as LongListSelector;
    if (selector == null)
        return;

   Odgovori odg = selector.SelectedItem as Odgovori;
     if (odg == null)
       return;

  if(odg.Tocno==null)
   MessageBox.Show("Try again");
    else MessageBox.Show("True!!!");
}
```

The problem here is that my object odg from the class Odgovori returns null after executing this code. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding a `string` to `Lista` that is why your casting is not working. If you have overridden your `ToString()` method in your `Odgovori` class I believe that the `LongListSelector` will call that method if you just add the `Odgovori` object to `Lista`